# IPV6-only issues

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, ipv6, ipv4

Apple announced ipv6-only policy few days ago at https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=05042016a.

Is this applicable to apps targeting to only iOS9 or lower versions?

I am using IPV4 address directly for HTTP request as http://x.x.x.x/path (Assume that I have to use address instead of host name, please do not argue about this point). It can be synthesized to IPV6 address by using NSURLConnection with IOS 9.2, but fails for lower IOS version.

Comment: Not arguing the address-vs-hostname point, but I am curious about the reasons. Does the app have to work even when there is a DNS failure?

Comment: For example we suffered serious DNS hijacking. We have our own HTTP DNS service for domain name resolving.

Comment: Interesting. You'll need a lot of changes in your code then. ISPs that use NAT64 also provide an accompanying DNS64 service. If you work around that you'll have to implement IPv6 there and synthesize IPv6 yourself when the server only has IPv4.

Answer (score 3):

It only has to work on the iOS versions that support synthesizing IPv6 addresses from IPv4 addresses.

See [this developer forum FAQ](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/46545#136166):

> #4 — My app relies on the system’s ability to synthesise an IPv6 address from an IPv4 address. What should I do on older systems?
>
> As described in Use System APIs to Synthesize IPv6 Addresses, starting
> with iOS 9.2 and OS X 10.11.2 you can use getaddrinfo to synthesise an
> IPv6 address from an IPv4 address.  Your app will be tested on a
> device running the latest released version of iOS, so you can assume
> that this support is present.

Comment: So it is according to your understanding of IPV6-onlty statement?

Comment: This answer is correct.  It is not possible to support IPv6-only configurations on earlier versions of iOS unless you have actual IPv6 addresses for your servers, and Apple is not mandating server-side changes, only client-side.

Comment: @Ryan: I have added a citation